# What is the algorithm details of Mathematica's FindRoot when "method" is the default Newton?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, arbitrary-precision, numerical-analysis, newtons-method

When solving a three-variate nonlinear system, I tried different implementations:

1) Mathemaitca; (FindRoot, default method)

2) Matlab programming(by using central finite difference to approximate Jacobian)

3) C++ (by using central finite difference to approximate Jacobian)

I found Mathematica works the best (solution precision, accuracy) even when the working precision is only "machine precision" without symbolic Jacobian provided.

However, Mathematica works slowest among the three.

Since my problem is very demanding in both "precision/accuracy" and efficiency, how can I replicate the default "Newton's" method in Matlab or C++?

thanks

Comment: I suspect that you will struggle to write a code which outperforms Mathematica and matches it for precision and accuracy.  Bear in mind that much of Mathematica's functionality is already coded in a language such as C or C++ and compiled.  You won't be trying to write a compiled code to outperform an interpreted language (which is one way of looking at Mathematica) but trying to write a code which outperforms compiled code written by specialists.  I'm not suggesting that you can't, just that it will be very difficult for you.

Comment: Thank you; I am new in C++; though the resulted difference by Mathematica and Matlab/C++ is only very small, for my problem the difference means completely different conclusions: right or wrong.  In order to obtain high precision solution, I have tried GMP/MPIR/MPFR/MPFR C++ wrapper/Eigen, I suspect something is wrong with some "interface" between such a "combination" of multiple precision libraries since they are from different developers. However, I cannot prove it unless I can replicate the Mathematica results via C++/Matlab implementation...

Comment: first be aware mathematica will take symbolic derivatives if it can, so for fair comparison be sure to supply purely numeric functions. Next you can add code to monitor function evaluations to try to learn whats going on.  You should take this to mathematica.stackexchange.com, but don't expect much help without some example code.

Comment: I suspect it is because the different methods in handling floating point numbers (either the round off methods, or representations of floating numbers); however, I have no idea of either Mathematica or the multiple precision Matlab/C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered here: [FindRoot algorithm details](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37804/what-are-the-algorithm-details-of-findroot)

However, there is no significant difference between their multiple precision implementations.